# select within an element which might be array or string in rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb, reql

My json in the rethinkdb database is as follows (I have given 4 docs as an example) :

```
    {
        "label": {
            "id": 59,
            "country": "Germany",
            "formats": {
                "format": {
                    "text": "",
                    "name": "CD",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "descriptions": {
                        "description": [
                            "Album",
                            "Limited Edition"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    {
        "label": {
            "id": 60,
            "country": "US",
            "formats": {
                "format": {
                    "text": "",
                    "name": "CD",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "descriptions": {
                        "description": "Album"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    {
        "label": {
            "formats": {
                "format": {
                    "text": "",
                    "name": "Vinyl",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "descriptions": {
                        "description": [
                            "12\"",
                            "33 ⅓ RPM"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "country": "US",
            "id": 42
        }
    }
{
    "label": {
        "formats": {
            "format": {
                "text": "",
                "name": "Vinyl",
                "qty": 1,
                "descriptions": {
                    "description": "12\""
                }
            }
        },
        "country": "US",
        "id": 10
    }
}
```

I would like to filter those labels which are albums. The description tag contains this information. However, this element is sometimes an array, sometimes a string. I need those labels which contains the value "Album" regardless the data type. So far I can only get those values where "description" is a string. This is the code I can use so far:

```
r.table("labels")('label').filter(r.row("formats")("format")("descriptions")("description").eq("Album"))('id')
```

Is there a way to get even those id values where Album exists within an array as well? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend changing your data format so that `description` is always an array, even if that array only has one element in it.  If you do that, then this query works:

```
r.table('labels')('label').filter(function(row) {
  return row("formats")("format")("descriptions")("description").contains('Album');
})
```

If you don't want to do that, then you can do this:

```
r.table('labels')('label').filter(function(row) {
  return row("formats")("format")("descriptions")("description").do(function(desc) {
    return r.branch(desc.typeOf().eq('ARRAY'), desc.contains('Album'), desc.eq('Album'));
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. If I changed the data format and then indexed it, would I be able to use "contains" on that index?

Comment: In that case you would need a multi-index: http://rethinkdb.com/docs/secondary-indexes/javascript/#multi-indexes